# Move articles only from Joomla 2.5 to 3.x

Tags: joomla, migration

I'm looking to take a Joomla 2.5 site to 3.4 but I only want to retain the articles, media and categories then use these to build the site again using Joomla 3.4, Gantry and K2. I specifically do not want to move any extensions or other items. The idea is to start with as clean a slate as possible keeping only the 2.5 site content.

I've looked for some time now for a way to do this but found nothing of use so far. Has anyone done this or know of a reliable method to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is make a copy of the database in another 2.5 instance. Then uninstall all the extensions you do not want and delete all the content in those extensions.  You need to make sure you do this using the API because there are many tables involved not just the main table for each extension. Make sure you delete any categories. THEN do the normal migration. Migrating com_content is basically trivial, just do the update within Joomla, it will automatically make any needed changes in the database.

Comment: Good idea and we did exactly that but found that there were still leftover bits that were causing issues. We want an entirely clean break from the 2.5 site other than content.

Comment: What were the leftover bits? Don't forget to clear out the menu.  Actually I always worry about the assets table but if you empty out the asset fields in the content and category tables and then reimport them into a J3 data base ... I believe the assets table will heal itself if you publish and unpublish the items.

Comment: The Joomla 2.5 site was itself upgraded from an older 1.5 site and has had many extensions, plugins, modifications, etc. over the years to the point that there are quite a few odd things in there which we couldn't get out and that were causing issues. I'd be more specific but thats as much as I understand of it.

Comment: Yes I have some sites like that and it's kind of a pain to carefully go though and clean them up.

Comment: We probably could clean it up for the most part but its like upgrading Windows versus a clean install; you can never get rid of all the leftovers and they tend to make trouble down the road.

Comment: We've been using J2XML for a week or so and it's exactly what we needed: it moves articles, categories and media and nothing else. We did have a problem with it because the XML files generated from our site were unusually large but we resolved it with some changes to the web server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this:

http://www.eshiol.it/ars/j2xml30-3-1-1/

Is the answer we've been looking for. It saves out only the Joomla 2.5+ content and images as an XML file which we will then import into a clean install of Joomla 3.4 - we are trying this now but it gets good reviews and has many downloads.